# How to improve delay when using google cast remote display

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cast

I followed this tutorial https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cast-unity-plugin/#0
to learn how to cast a unity game on a chromecast.

It works and the result is bad. There is almost one second of delay between my actions and their display on my tv. (I pulled the frame rate down to 15 FPS and it didn't change anything).

I was wondering if it was useless to try making an action game on chromecast with the remote display or if there were some workarounds. I didn't find any article about that problem. Is this related to the network protocol ? Is there a way to change it (I guess it isn't) ?

Well, I'm deeply disappointed really.

[EDIT] My android device is a Nexus 7 (with Marshmallow). The chromecast is the last one. As for my wi-fi, everything seems ok, but how can I test it (on ubuntu 14.04 system) ? I tried on another wi-fi network (a mobile hotspot) and had the same result (maybe a mobile hotspot isn't relevant)...
And I tried this : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hillmanworks.drawcast and the performance is rather good. So my network is not the problem (at least not a "standalone" problem).

[EDIT2] The strange thing is, that when mirroring my device, the performance is much better than when casting directly from the unity app... this is not my network.

[EDIT3] I made a very simple app (from the roll a ball tutorial from unity site), and I still have a 1 sec delay (on a nexus 7). The same example on a cheap acer tablet, I have 5 sec delay. The thing is, for both devices, if I try to play this simple app through device screen mirroring, the delay is maybe 0.3 seconds (much better). I don't know what to think.

Comment: How do other apps perform on our combination of devices? Are you sure this problem isn't caused by you network or hardware?

Comment: In fact I don't know. This is the purpose of my question : where to investigate ? I don't even know what performances are intended to be ? I didn't see any technical data anywhere about that.

Comment: Download some apps for your device that support streaming to chrome cast and see how they perform, im sure there's also a benchmark app to test the connection you got to the cc.

Comment: This is the app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.libspeed4cast.app

Comment: Thanks. This app doesn't work. But I tried another one https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hillmanworks.drawcast which allows me to draw on my tv, and the latency is pretty good (not perfect but far better than the one I have with my google tutorial app). So my network is not the main reason of my poor result, and it's possible to have playable performance (that's a good news). Now, what next ?

Comment: is there a chance you could just make a very simple demo, to see if your own program is causing the trouble?

Comment: well, I tried the google tutorial example. If I follow the tutorial, I have the problem, if I download the finished app, I have the problem, if I try doing a simpler example, I have the problem. If I try playing without casting from my app, but mirroring my device, it's much better (of course not perfect but almost playable). If I try with an app from play store (castpad), it works very well... so ? I don't know what to think really. I'm on ubuntu 14.04, could it be a problem with a library ?